# Ubuntu Server compiling kernel modules

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel

I am trying to compile paragon ntfs driver http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-linux-per/screenshots.html and got “no symbol version for module_layout" error when modprobe loading modules.
According to answer ["no symbol version for module_layout" when trying to load usbhid.ko](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14627/no-symbol-version-for-module-layout-when-trying-to-load-usbhid-ko) I should have the same versions of linux-source, linux-headers and running kernel.
I have Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS  uname -r 3.8.0-44-generic, but no linux-source-3.8.0-44 and linux-headers-3.8.0-44 in repositary.

Where i can got linux-source-3.8.0-44 and linux-headers-3.8.0-44?
Thanks
Konstantin

Answer (score 0):

You can install this from the precise repo, 3.8 was the default kernel on 12.04.
You're on 14.04, thus your sources.lst points towards trusty:

Either download the packages from here and install then using `dpkg -i <pkgname>`
http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/linux-headers-3.8.0-44
http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/linux-headers-3.8.0-44-generic

or add the old repo to your sources.lst and install from there.

Searching on http://packages.ubuntu.com doesn't yield results for `linux-source...` though.

Comment: Thanks, I have migrated from 12.04. I prefer to upgrade kernel to 3.13. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade gives me nothing.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` would upgrade to a new release. If you have issues with apt, try `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`. Anyqay, please open another question for this separate issue.